# Hide title bar but not action bar Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am using ActionBar from Appcompat and also tabs in my activity.
But in lower Android versions ( like in 2.3), i am also getting the title bar of the activity above the action bar. This title bar is not coming in higher android versions( 4.0 etc)

So to hide the title bar

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

works well in Android 2.3 but crashes in higher versions because i think it removes the complete ActionBar also and so `getActionBar()` retutrns null. But why it crashes in  higher Android versions only?

Also how do i remove the Title bar then in lower Android versions then?

```
actionbar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

The above code hides the title of the action bar instead but not the title bar of the activity.

Comment: Add a version checking condition before this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi, that will be the last resort :)